# Implementing interfaces

Tags: java, interface

I know what interface is and how to build/use one. Lets take the ActionListener interface for example.
My question is what happens after I click on a button, which class calls the actionPerformed method?what is the process from the part that I click the button to the part that the actionPerformed is executed?

Comment: Is that ActionListener android or swing?

Comment: Speaking generally, but if it matters the swing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JButton` calls the `ActionListener`.

Internally, it listens to keyboard and mouse events. When it receives a mouse click or a keypress which means "click the button", it creates an `ActionEvent` instance, loops through all the `ActionListener` instances that have been added to itself, and calls each one with the `ActionEvent` as argument.